# procedure returns null value

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have written a simple demo procedure below is the code

```
delimiter //
create procedure test2(IN boss int, out name varchar(50))
begin
select Name into name  from employee where Reports_to=boss;
end //
```

when I call this procedure as `CALL test2(2,@name)` it returns null

though the table has all the values -

```
mysql> select * from employee;
+--------+--------+--------+-------------+------------+
| Emp_Id | Name   | Salary | Department  | Reports_to |
+--------+--------+--------+-------------+------------+
|      1 | Alok   |  50000 | RnD         |       NULL |
|      2 | Mahesh |  40000 | Development |          1 |
|      3 | Ramesh |  40000 | Development |          1 |
|      4 | Bimal  |  30000 | Sales       |          2 |
|      5 | Javed  |  20000 | Marketing   |          4 |
|      6 | Mukesh |  35000 | Accounts    |          3 |
+--------+--------+--------+-------------+------------+
```

and also If I write `CALL test2(1,@name)` it shows error

> result contains more than one row

how to solve these two errors...??

Comment: Procedure can't return multiple values so you need
Add `LIMIT 1` to your query

Comment: Avoid naming variables or parameters as the name of your columns.

Comment: @Artem llchenko could you please specify with the syntax I am trying to add limit 1 but it gives error..??

Answer (score 2):

The below query fails as it can't assign more than one value to a variable:

```
select Name into name  from employee where Reports_to=boss;
```

What you want is something like `GROUP_CONCAT` which would return comma separated values. Try the following:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) INTO names
FROM employee
WHERE reports_to = boss;
```

Comment: @ Darshan Mehta it doen't give the error "result contains more than one value" but it still returns NULL see this..                                   mysql> select @name;
+-------+
| @name |
+-------+
| NULL  |
+-------+

Comment: Updated the answer, try now?

Comment: it gives the error  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY Emp_Id;

Comment: Okay, removed `GROUP BY`. Could you try adding `name IS NOT NULL` into example or just try the query without `GROUP_CONCAT` in CLI and post the output?

Comment: without GROUP_CONCAT it gives error "Result contains more than one value"

Comment: I meant, you can try running it into CLI without `INTO` etc and see the records it's returning.

Comment: that is the syntax without INTO how will it assign the result to input variables??

Comment: We don't need to assign any values just now. We can just see how many values/rows it returns.

Comment: I got the result I just changed the variable name "name " to any other name..it shouldn't be same as any of the columns name...

Comment: Great, I have updated my answer for future reference.